# How to insert element on event being fired in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, events, meteor, scope, dom-events

If I had a template like this:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <ul>
    <li>We're</li>
    <li>all</li>
    <li list items</li>
  </ul>

  <button>My Button</button>
</template>
```

And my event handler looked like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click button': function(e, t) {
    //...
  }
});
```

How could I add an element to the list in the template, from the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ordinary DOM manipulation:

```js
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click button': function(e, t) {
        var ul = t.find('ul')
        var newLi = document.createElement('li')
        newLi.innerHTML = "Hello!"
        ul.appendChild(newLi)
    }
});
```